# Truncating Floating point creating additional errors? (AS3)

Tags: floating-point, truncate, deterministic

I am trying to build a **deterministic simulation**, where the floating point numbers are truncated off via the following function:
(I found it here: http://joshblog.net/2007/01/30/flash-floating-point-number-errors )

```
return Math.round(10000 * float) / 10000;
```

My question is: wouldn't the fact that I am **dividing it by 10000, be in itself a source of floatpoint errors?**
IE every time a dividision takes place, it will result in a new float with further possible nondeterministic results.

EDIT:
how about this? using only powers of 2

```
return Math.round(float* 1024) / 1024;
```

Comment: This generally not an appropriate way to make floating-point code deterministic. Basic floating-point operations are completely deterministic, and making software deterministic is largely a matter of ensuring the compiler or interpreter uses the specific operations you intended. (For cross-platform or cross-version determinism, controlling the libraries is also important, since routines like log use approximations, which may vary between vendors and versions.) If you want to quantize as you ask, there are ways to do it with no scaling error, such as by using powers of 2 instead of 10.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric, it is indeed a Cross-platform issue, but as one of the platforms is Flash/Actionscript, using a Fixedpoint struct(with a 2 based shift) is not an option.
Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Then it is a language/environment issue that I am not qualified to speak to, since I do not work in Flash/Actionscript. In particular, I do not know if Actionscript is specified well enough to guarantee identical floating-point operations on different platforms. I can say the division will only introduce a very small error, and it will be deterministic unless the compiler/interpreter modifies it (e.g., multiplying by a reciprocal instead), combines it with other operation, or uses extended precision for intermediate calculations.

Comment: Additionally, note that rounding to multiples of a quantum helps only if you know that the errors so far have not accumulated to more than half of the quantum. Otherwise, the rounding operation may round to an undesired value.

Comment: Yes, this 'rounding' would be applied to each individual function/statement that could result in a float ( otherwise the application runs off Integers) So how about modifying the above function to round off based on powers of 2?
return Math.round(float* 1024) / 1024;
- would this make it more deterministic?

Comment: With binary floating-point, multiplying and dividing by powers of two never introduce rounding errors, except when the result overflows the exponent range (and produces infinity) or underflows (and loses bits at the low end). Also, do not divide by 1024; multiply by its reciprocal. Multiplication is typically faster than division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goal was to achieve **greater** consistency across platforms(C# / AS3 and 32/64 bits), while I accept that 100% consistency is not possible.
(due to AS3 not capable of real integer math, as all internal operations are performed via floats)

What I have gathered so far( Thanks to Eric Postpischil and Jeffrey Sax):

```
Math.round(1024 * float) / 1024;
```

Out of the above, the "**Math.round(1024 * float)**" operation may NOT produce identical results on all platforms, if the "*errors have accumulated to more than half of the quantum*" which is possible even "*within a single operation*".

- While this is mathematically possible, it is likely to be very rare, so overall this operation will still **eliminate more inconsistencies than it would generate**, so it is worthwhile to perform it as it will reduce inconsistency across platforms (though cannot eliminate them)

.

Where as for the **"/ 1024"** part, as 1024 is a power of 2, that is a *straight bit shift*, it will NOT introduce extra errors, where as if I divided by 1000 that would introduce a small chance of an extra error, as 1000 cannot be perfectly represented. So a division with 1000 could introduce another error after the rounding which the division by 1024 could not.

.

*CONCLUSION:* **Math.round(1024 * float) / 1024; is better** than Math.round(1000 * float) / 1000; although neither of them is perfect.

Is this an accurate statement?

Answer (score 3):

When you say deterministic, I'm assuming you want a **reproducible** simulation, where you get the exact same results every time you run the simulation.

To make this happen, you need to find the source of possible variation and eliminate it.

The only way is to compile to a binary for a specific architecture.

Floating-point arithmetic itself is fully specified. The floating-point standards (IEEE-754) are followed by all modern processors and leave no ambiguity.

There are two main variations:

1. **Differences in instruction sets.** This is the most obvious one. If you compile your application to 32 or 64 bit, you will likely get slightly different results. 32 bit applications tend to use older style x87 instructions which use 80 bit intermediate values. This causes some results to be rounded differently. Even on x86 there are differences, if you use SSE instructions, which work on multiple operands at once. Some compilers may generate code that depends on how operands are aligned in memory.
2. **Differences in instruction ordering.** Mathematically, `(a+b)+c` and `a+(b+c)` are equivalent (addition is *associative*). In floating-point calculations this is not the case. If `a` is one, `b` is minus one, and `c` a tiny number so that `1+c` gets rounded to `1`, then the expressions evaluate to `c` and `0`, respectively. It is the compiler that decides which instructions to use. Depending on your language  and platform, it may be the language compiler or the Just-in-Time IL/bytecode compiler. Either way, the compiler is a black box, and it may change the way it compiles code without our knowledge. The smallest difference can lead to a different end result.

The rounding approach looks nice in theory, but it doesn't work. No matter how you round, there are always cases where two different but equivalent sets of instructions produce a result that gets rounded differently.

The core reason is that rounding is not composable, in the sense that rounding to `a` digits, and then rounding to `b (< a)` digits is not equivalent to rounding to `b` digits from the beginning. For example: 1.49 rounded to one digit is 1.5 and rounding that to zero digits gives 2. But rounding to zero digits directly yields 1.

So, on an x87-based system which uses 80-bit 'extended' precision for intermediate values, you start with 64 significant bits. You can round this down directly to your desired precision. If you have double-precision intermediates, you get *the same intermediate result, but rounded to 53 significant bits*, which is then rounded to your desired precision.

Your only option is to produce machine code for a specific architecture.

Now, if your goal is only to minimize the differences instead of completely eliminating them, then the answer is straightforward: dividing or multiplying by a power of two (like 1024) does not introduce any additional round-off error in the range used by your application, while multiplying and dividing by a number like 1000 does.

If you look at accumulating errors as a random walk, then using 1000 for rounding requires more steps than using 1024. Both the multiplication and the division may introduce additional errors. So on average, the total error will be larger, and so you have a bigger chance that the rounding operation goes the wrong way. This is even true when you round on every operation.

Comment: wow thats a lot of information! thanks, how about the dividing with 1024 (ie powers of 2)? wouldn't that make it consistent across different platforms?
(Compiling to specific architecture is not an option, as its cross platform, ie one client is Flash/AS3 another one is C# )

Comment: In addition to those, there are problems with instruction contraction (such as replacing a*b+c with a fused multiply-add instruction) or other operation rewriting by the compiler/interpreter, differences in library routines (different vendors‘ log routines return different results), non-standard modes (denormals flushed to zeroes).

Comment: It is not true that the standards leave no ambiguity. For example, underflow may be detected before rounding or after rounding.

Comment: There is a list of things to do to obtain reproducible results on pages 51-52 of the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic—2008. They require cooperation from the language processor et cetera.

Comment: Thanks Eric for all this info, however it does not relate to my question. The epsilon is always very small, so rounding the float to a precision of 3-4 decimals will make any cross-platform inconsistencies disappear. My question was simply if by the act of dividing it with 1000, am I exposing my self to extra errors, and if by using 1024 instead (which is a power of 2) this could be eliminated?

Comment: @MartinK I've added an explicit explanation of why rounding is never fail-safe.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey! But wouldn't what you have said assume (1) accumulated errors and (2) Epsilons larger than what would affect 3 decimals? Where as there would not be accumulated errors as all floats would be immediately cast to int, and the rest of the program only deals with ints, and I do not know of any CPU specification that would produce epsilons larger than what would affect 3 decimals?? IE all errors I've seen so far were like 0.9990000000000001 instead of 0.999. Im looking for a simple explanation of **if dividing an integer by 1024 is more platform cross-consistent than with 1000**?

Comment: @JeffreySax, I think your comments about composition of rounding miss the mark, because that is not the source of non-determinism here. Errors caused by rounding twice would apparently be perfectly acceptable to Martin K provided they were identical on different machines. The actual problem is that a single rounding may produce different results, if the error in its input may exceed half the rounding quantum on one machine and be less than half the quantum on another machine (with additional complications for cases where it is exactly half the quantum).

Comment: @MartinK, there are **no** CPU specifications that prevent “epsilons” larger than three decimals. The amount of error in a result is a function of the operations performed on it, and error analysis is a complicated task. It is possible for operations to produce an arbitrarily large error. (E.g., if you have an x with some amount of error x' and you multiply by y [which we suppose is exact], then the error is x'•|y|. So, if y is large, the error is large. And, if you have a z that is nearly equal to x, and you calculate (x-z)•y, then the relative error is large.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, yes but as I said the inconsistencies are NEVER larger on any platform, than 3 decimals, so it really doesnt matter how different the same calculation yield on the last **'0000000000001'**  parts, as when you apply the rounding method in my OP that wont influence the first the first 3 decimals.

Comment: How do you **know** the inconsistencies are never larger than .001?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, you are talking about accumulated errors, which I've just said will NOT exist in my case, as each time a float is used it is immediately 'sanitized' with the function in my OP and then cast to int. And the rest of the program only uses ints.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, without accumulated errors there is no CPU that would produce THAT inaccurate representation of a number. No CPU that isnt faulty!

Comment: I demonstrated a single operation that can produce arbitrarily large error. Therefore, rounding after each single floating-point operation is insufficient to guarantee determinism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code demonstrating that rounding to multiples of a quantum does not produce deterministic results, even when there is no error in scaling.

The output I get is:

```
Machine 0 produces 0x1p+0 (1).
Machine 1 produces 0x1.004p+0 (1.0009765625).
The results differ.
```

The source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


// Round a value to the nearest multiple of the quantum.
static double Quantize(double x)
{
    static const double Quantum = 1024., InverseQuantum = 1/Quantum;

    return round(x * Quantum) * InverseQuantum;
}


int main(void)
{
    /*  For this example, we are in the middle of some calculation, where we
        have some value a from earlier operations.  a0 and a1 represent the
        calculated values of a on two different platforms.  Observe that the
        difference is as small as possible, just a single ULP.
    */
    double a0 = 0x1.cbd9f42000000p0;
    double a1 = 0x1.cbd9f42000001p0;

    // Define a constant that the calculation uses.
    double b = 0x1.1d2b9fp-1;

    // Calculate the pre-quantization result on each machine.
    double x0 = a0 * b;
    double x1 = a1 * b;

    // Quantize the result on each machine.
    double y0 = Quantize(x0);
    double y1 = Quantize(x1);

    // Display the results.
    printf("Machine 0 produces %a (%.53g).\n", y0, y0);
    printf("Machine 1 produces %a (%.53g).\n", y1, y1);
    printf("The results %s.\n", y0 == y1 ? "are identical" : "differ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eric I do accept this now, that the rounding operation **MAY** not eliminate all inconsistencies across platforms but it will still more likely to reduce them? Have a look at my own 'conclusions' answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by 10,000 results in a rounding error equal to the difference between the exact mathematical result and the nearest number representable in double-precision, assuming IEEE 754 binary floating-point arithmetic in round-to-nearest mode. This error is at most 1/2 ULP (unit of least precision) of the result.

Multiplying by a power of two, rounding to an integer, and dividing by the same power of two will not cause have any errors in the rounding operations except: Multiplication with an exact result around 2<sup>1024</sup> (the exact threshold is slightly slower) or greater will produce a floating-point infinity. (In general, multiplication or division by powers of two can produce rounding errors when the result underflows the floating-point range, that is, when the exact mathematical result is in (0, 2<sup>-1022</sup>). However, underflow will not occur when calculating round(x*p)/p for p some positive power of 2 less than 2<sup>1023</sup>.)

Quantizing numbers in this way will not in general produce deterministic results. Deviations between two platforms may occur when pre-quantization values have errors may straddle midpoints between quanta.

Comment: "_Multiplying by a power of two, rounding to an integer, and dividing by the same power of two will not cause have any errors in the rounding operations except:_ **Multiplication with an exact result around 2^1024 (the exact threshold is slightly slower) or greater will produce a floating-point infinity. "**
- in plain english, are you saying that if the values I am working which are < 2^31, IE Integer sized, then the method of multiplying by 1024 and dividing by 1024 will produce Cross platform consistent results ???

Comment: No, I am saying that multiplying by a power of two produces no error and dividing by a power of two produces no error. However, this is not where the problem in your method lies. The problem lies in the round operation. The round operation is incapable of transforming non-deterministic results into deterministic results, in the absence of proof that the inputs to round do not straddle midway points.

Comment: Eric, I do realise that without fixed point maths or true integer only maths it is NOT possible to be 100% deterministic, but as I also said one of my target languages is **AS3, which is incapable of true integer maths**, so I know it is not going to be perfect, but I am looking for the **least bad** solution, and from what you are saying it appears that **multiplying1024->rounding->dividing1024**
will introduce less extra errors than by doing the same with a 1000. So with all things being equal 1024 is better than 1000, there may still be errors, but less likely, Yes??

Comment: Rounding operands not known to be on the same side of the midway point on different platforms is unreliable.

Comment: Ok putting it in another way, making the "arbitary" assumption of epsilon < .0001, which of out of the two options 1024 or 1000 is LESS likely to produce an error?

Comment: IE, with all else being equal and 'assuming' that the rounding operation produced the same result on both CPUs, **so all we are doing is performing a division with either 1024 or 1000 on the same integer** result on 2 different CPUs.

Comment: (a) epsilon is undefined. If, by epsilon, you mean the absolute error in an operand to round or the absolute error in x in the expression round(x*q), then no, the conclusion that the result of rounding is deterministic is unsupported. (b) I will not assume rounding operands containing different errors on different platforms produces the same result because the assumption is known to be false. Producing a proof of correctness from false axioms is a path  to making buggy software.

Comment: OK well in my applications the rounding operation always produced an identical result, in all cases. You are right this isnt mathematically always the case, but it is still better to do this than to leave it as it is. But this was not even in the question, and I have never asked you to comment on this. I have asked which is better if all else is being equal, dividing by 1000 or 1024.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I learned a lot from this discussion. I think the round and /1000 trick is an old trick ActionScript developers uses to use based on a crazy TechNote Adobe published (that was so shameful it was since erased even from archive.org).  Is there a way to know which particular ieee754 numbers are not wholly representable via a double-precision floating point number? In other words, to generate a set of test inputs formatted as strings (or big decimals) and convert them to doubles to demonstrate truncation and rounding issues?

Comment: @JohnZabroski: The only representable finite numbers in the IEEE-754 “double precision” format (binary64) are those that equal a signed 53-bit integer (sign plus 53 bits) multiplied by a power of two between 2^−1074 and 2^+971 (inclusive). Finding test inputs to demonstrate issues generally requires analysis using both the operations to be performed, the other data to be used, and the floating-point format.

Comment: @JohnZabroski: For the quantization function proposed in this function, finding examples is simple: As we progress along the real number line, the output of the quantization function must step (in quantum leaps) from one output to another. At the point where it does so, there are two adjacent floating-point numbers, one with one quantization output and the other with another. And therefore a slight error at that point will be magnified by the quantization function to a large error. Those points are easy to find, just find where the quantization output changes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Put another way, how did you know one CPU allows representing a number as `0x1.cbd9f42000000p0` and another CPU allows representing a number as `0x1.cbd9f42000001p0`? This seems like awfully specific numbers to "pick out of a hat"?

One intuition I have had is Guy Lewis Steele and William Clinger writing a pair of papers for how to serialize and de-serialize floats. Steele's rule was: Print the smallest possible number you can represent ("How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately"). Clinger's was the inverse ("How to Read Floating-Point Numbers Accurately").

Comment: @EricPostpischil Another intuition I developed is to construct representible numbers by leaving the mantissa as all zeroes.  However, that does not tell me how to pick an un-representible number "out of a hat", not does it tell me an analytical approach to constructing pairs of numbers that force an un-representible value to occur. I think I almost have the right line of thinking but not quite there. Apologies if the answer is embedded in your quantization approach. It seems like an expensive way to find the answer across the entire ieee numberspace. If mantissa = 1.0, it's an exact match.

Comment: @JohnZabroski: CPUs do not “represent a number as” one floating-point number or another. The conversion of decimal numbers to binary floating-point is well specified and should be deterministic. Differences between floating-point calculations arise not because of how decimal numbers are converted to floating-point but because different environments may use different floating-point formats, may use different implementations of the various transcendental functions (which mathematically could be deterministic, but computing them is hard, so implementations that are not correctly rounded are…

Comment: … used), calculations are partitioned over multiple threads, and the partitioning and later recombination of results are non-deterministic because they depend on timing, because some environments might not properly support subnormal reasons, and more. So it happens that, over the course of calculations, the results obtained diverge. It is in that environment that OP seeks to make things deterministic. My example demonstrates that does not work; the attempt to eliminate small errors by quantizing is doomed to fail, in the absence of rare specific conditions.